# Combine fields from joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

One category can have many products. I have to build StoredProcedure that returns all categories with some data from Products combined into one field:

```
SP Result:
idCategory Name   ProductNames         ProductQuantities 
1          Cat1   Procut1,Product2     24,32
2          Cat2   ProductX,ProductY    0,61
```

ProductNames and ProductQuantities are varchar fields with combined (concatenated) field values from joined Product tables. This is what I have in DB:

```
Category table:
idCategory   Name
1            Cat1
2            Cat2

Product table:
idProduct  idCategory Name      Quantity 
1          1          Product1  24
2          1          Product2  32
3          2          ProductX  0
4          2          ProductY  61
```

I would also like to have Function, that returns "Product1,Product2" for input parameter idCategory=1, like this:

```
SELECT idCategory, 
       dbo.NamesFn(idCategory) AS ProductNames,
       dbo.QuantitiesFn(idCategory) AS ProductQuantities 
FROM Category
```

maybe one function that returns Table Result, so joining would be done only once, not in every Fn (because this is simplified example, in real app I have to have 4-5 combined fields, or even more in the future)?

How to write that SQL / SP & Fn? I'm using MS SQL2005

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions for concatenating rows using SQL Server. See [this](http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-from-a-column-into-a-single-row.html), and [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=79050).

This query produces the result set you asked for:

```
select c.idCategory, c.Name,
    replace(
        (select p.Name as [data()]
         from Product p
     where p.idCategory = c.idCategory
     for xml path ('')
), ' ', ', ') as ProductNames,
    replace(
        (select p.Quantity as [data()]
         from Product p
     where p.idCategory = c.idCategory
     for xml path ('')
), ' ', ', ') as ProductQuantities 
from Category c
```

Edited to add:
This query produces the result:

```
idCategory  Name    ProductNames          ProductQuantities
1           Cat1    Product1, Product2    24, 32
2           Cat2    ProductX, ProductY    0, 61
```

Comment: i already found those examples through google, but don't know have to build Function that returns Table result, and how to include that results to SP results

Comment: @Tom H but not for function with Table result

Comment: @Hrvoje: I think you are having problem searching for your problem.  The keyword you should search with is "Table-Valued" function

Comment: @jamie I love seeing creaitive answer like this so that I can learn from it ad well

Comment: no. it didn't work. I had to use COALESCE and several sql functions. But thanx for this example, i learned from it a lot

Comment: @Hrvoje -- I actually created a database and populated it with the data from your question. This solution does work for the question as stated. I'll re-run it and add the query result to my answer.